# EnvironmentValues getter is being called on app launch without access

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

I have a custom EnvironmentValue defined as:

```
private struct DataProviderKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: DataProvider = {
        fatalError()
    }()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var dataProvider: DataProvider {
        get {
            self[DataProviderKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[DataProviderKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

And main function looks like this:

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MyView()
                .environment(\.dataProvider, MyDataProvider())
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that the `defaultValue` won't be accessed as I inject the environment on App Launch. But before that happens, there's another call to the `var dataProvider: DataProvider` getter that I am not invoking.

Stack trace doesn't reveal much information as well:
[image]

So my question is why is the getter being invoked by the system? Even if I remove the access with keyPath `.environment(\.dataProvider, MyDataProvider())` it still gets called at the same point in time. I don't want to provide a default value because I want to know whenever such value is not injected immediately.

Comment: "Why is the getter invoked by the system?" I would assume that the call to `.environment` populates some sort of hash table of environment values. This seems like expected behavior.